# show or hide polyline as layer in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, velocity, polyline

I have a JSON with different points. Each point has a different fields, like `lon1` , `lat1`, `lon2`, `lat2`.

For each point I draw a line from point 1 to point 2.
By means of a `for` I perform this operation for each point and I draw different polylines in the map.

The problem is that when I activate or deactivate the layer, **only the last drawn line is hidden, not all lines.**

In the map you can see all the lines, but it seems that in the layer it overwrites and deletes the last line generated.

**Code:**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features.length; i++) {

  var Lon1 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['Lon(d.dd)'];
  var Lat1 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['Lat(d.dd)'];
  var Lon2 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['LON2'];
  var Lat2 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['LAT2'];

  // array of coordinates
  var mylatlngs = [
    [Lat1, Lon1],
    [Lat2, Lon2]
  ];
  // draw a polyline in the map
  var polilineas = L.polyline(mylatlngs, {
    color: 'blue'
  });
  polilineas.addTo(map);

  // add " polilineas" into other layer
  var Velocidad2D = new L.LayerGroup();
  Velocidad2D.addLayer(polilineas);
  // Velocidad2D.addLayer(cabezas);  Possibility to add arrow head
}


// Code to LAYER CONTROL

var gropedOverlayslehen = {
  "Vel 2D": Velocidad2D
}

var layerControl = L.control.layers(basemaps, gropedOverlayslehen);

layerControl.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Ah, a classical variable scope problem. Do read about closures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `var Velocidad2D = new L.LayerGroup();` to the outside of the loop, else you overwrite it everytime.

```
var Velocidad2D = new L.LayerGroup();
for (var i = 0; i < json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features.length; i++) {

  var Lon1 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['Lon(d.dd)'];
  var Lat1 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['Lat(d.dd)'];
  var Lon2 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['LON2'];
  var Lat2 = json_ARAPointsPRU_0.features[i].properties['LAT2'];

  // array of coordinates
  var mylatlngs = [
    [Lat1, Lon1],
    [Lat2, Lon2]
  ];
  // draw a polyline in the map
  var polilineas = L.polyline(mylatlngs, {
    color: 'blue'
  });
  polilineas.addTo(map);

  // add " polilineas" into other layer
  Velocidad2D.addLayer(polilineas);
  // Velocidad2D.addLayer(cabezas);  Possibility to add arrow head
}


// Code to LAYER CONTROL

var gropedOverlayslehen = {
  "Vel 2D": Velocidad2D
}

var layerControl = L.control.layers(basemaps, gropedOverlayslehen);

layerControl.addTo(map);
```